# Test at runtime if a cast would compile

Tags: java, reflection

Given two `java.lang.Class` objects `dst` and `src` and assuming that they represent the types `Y` and `X` respectively, I would like a function `public static boolean isCastCompilable(Class dst, Class src)` that returns `true` if and only if the statements `X x; Y y = ((Y)x);` would compile for those types `X` and `Y`.

Here is a first attempt at hand-coding these rules:

```java
public class Compilable {

    public boolean isCastCompilable(Class dstClass, Class srcClass) {
        if (Objects.equals(srcClass, dstClass)) {
            return true;
        }
        
        if (Boolean.TYPE.equals(srcClass)) {
            return false; // Boolean cannot be converted explicity to any primitive type:
            // https://javajee.com/casting-of-primitives-in-java
        }

... more code

        return false;
    }
}
```

For instance, this function would return `true` for `isCastCompilable(java.util.List.class, java.util.ArrayList.class)` because the statements `java.util.ArrayList x; java.util.List y = ((java.util.List)x);` would be valid Java code that a compiler would accept.

It should return `false` for `isCastCompilable(Boolean.TYPE, String.class)` because `String x; boolean y = (boolean)x;` would be rejected by the compiler.

**My question:** Is there a straight-forward way of implementing `isCastCompilable` or will I have to handcode all the casting rules myself, the way I started doing in the code example above?

**Context:** I am making a kind of Java code generator and would like to test if the code that performs casts will compile in order not to emit invalid code.

Comment: I think you want this: [Class.isAssignableFrom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-)

Comment: @rghome Interesting. It could be that `src.isAssignableFrom(dst) || dst.isAssignableFrom(src)` would be equivalent to `isCastCompilable(dst, src)` but I would have to test that...

Comment: @Rulle I don't think that's the case. Your "if and only if" means that you only want one of the two cases to be true. I can't tell which is which because you change nomenclature from `src` and `dst` to `x` and `y`.

Comment: @AndyTurner No. That is not what "if and only if" means.

Comment: You may want to read up the [JLS §5.5 Casting Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5). Short version: If A and B are both not interfaces, they need to be related. Doesn't apply to interfaces, some special case if A is final (there can be no possible subclass that implements B if A doesn't implement it...).

Comment: Also `Boolean b1 = Boolean.TRUE; boolean b2 = (boolean) b1;` works fine - there are things that can be casted to `boolean`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I appreciate your efforts. If you can implement this and submit an answer, feel free to do that. Otherwise, I will go with the solution that I submitted as an answer. It is not pretty but it does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

*Answering my own question:* Generate a piece of code for the cast that we want to test for and try to compile it with the Janino compiler to see if it is a valid cast or not:

```
import org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler;

public class CastableInfo {
    public boolean testIfCastCompilable(Class dst, Class src) {
        String Y = dst.getName();
        String X = src.getName();
        String sampleCode = "public class TestCast {public "
            + Y + " convert(" + X + " x) {return (" + Y + ")x;}}";
        SimpleCompiler cl = new SimpleCompiler();
        try {
            cl.cook(sampleCode);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```